# Installing Homebrew in Catalina without Xcode Command Line Tools

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I try to install homebrew without Xcode Command Line Tools.

I tried to manipulate homebrew install code, here's the script:
https://gist.github.com/tolgafiratoglu/ddff5dd0fe813c4952cceecccfa535ce

I changed this definition of this method so it always return false:

```
def should_install_command_line_tools?
  return false
end
```

Also I commented out all lines with xcode, and run:

```
ruby homebrew-install.rb
```

but it still tries to install xcrun prompt.

What am I missing?

Comment: the script will always run `xcrun` (line 318)... maybe you can install xcode and then follow this instrux to get rid off it https://shawnliu.me/post/homebrew-without-xcode/